# JWT - JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken not transforming email claim to emailaddress claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

In JwtSecurityTokenHandler, how can we transform the email address claim to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress` claim. There's a property `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap` which holds the mapping of short name claims and their long claim names, however it's not transforming the claims as it should be?

Posting the sample jwt token which if we send into a .net core app, it transforms the email claim to emailaddress claim, however, it's not transforming in the unit test projects since the aspnet pipeline is not hooked up? Per documentation ReadJwtToken method should handle it but it's not.

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var id_token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDUwNjAzNDIsImV4cCI6MTY3NjU5NjM0MiwiYXVkIjoid3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoianJvY2tldEBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoiYmVlQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIn0.pRY2xBjQ3HcdEWmh1I1QKXlhjng8CXGINrYbpI0Xg-c";
        var jwtTokenHanlder = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwtTokenAsJwtToken = jwtTokenHanlder.ReadJwtToken(id_token);
        foreach (var item in jwtTokenAsJwtToken.Claims)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Type} : {item.Value}");
        }    
    }
}

/* output

iss : Online JWT Builder
iat : 1645060342
exp : 1676596342
aud : www.example.com
sub : jrocket@example.com
email : bee@example.com
*/
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FqD4cZ

Comment: so you want emailadress instead of email? It caused by your token. How do you get this token?

Comment: yes, I used this site to mock jwt token. http://jwtbuilder.jamiekurtz.com/